# How can i install Google's CP solver OR-Tools in MiniZinc?

Tags: installation, solver, constraint-programming, or-tools, minizinc

I'm currently working on MiniZinc, and i have been running my models with the two solvers integrated in MiniZinc: Gecode and Chuffed. I've been running it in the IDE, but i am aware that it can be runned in bash too (using `minizinc` command).

But i would like to test how my models do with Google's CP solver, called OR-Tools. But i really don't know how. I got the MiniZinc snap installation in Ubuntu 18.04, but i can download a fresh directory of MiniZinc and run it locally, and configure the solver there (and not in snap installation since snap directories can not be modified).

I need a way to install OR-Tools and make it work at least in the terminal (but run it from the IDE would be perfect).

Comment: You can get the flatzinc binaries of ortools here: https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MiniZinc uses [solver configuration files](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.0/en/fzn-spec.html#solver-configuration-files) to find the available solver. If, however, the solver does not provide a configuration file. The IDE can help you add a user configuration file for the solver in the following simple steps.

1. Open the preferences window.
2. In the solver selection, select "Add new..."

[image: Add new solver]

3. Enter the details of the solver you want to add. Most importantly the location of the executable and the location of their MiniZinc library.

[image: Enter Solver details]

##### Edit/Addition: Obtaining the necessary executables

As mentioned by Stradivari in the comment above, *releases are distributed at [or-tools @ Github](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases)*.

Pick the corresponding asset from one of those following the `or-tools_{XXX}_{VERSION}.zip` naming scheme.

Comment: It supports -a, -n, -s, -v, -p, -f, -t. Not sure about -r

Comment: By the way @Dekker1 how can you do this in MiniZinc Command Line? I'm trying to build a docker container with MiniZinc + OR Tools solver installed by default.

Comment: You can just copy the file created by the IDE (store in `.minizinc/solvers`) to you Docker image

Comment: I installed or-tools with pip in MacOS, but I don't find any bin folder in "/Users/my_name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages". Is it at somewhere else?

Comment: The full path is "/Users/my_name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/ortools"

Comment: the minizinc interpreter is not a python package.

Comment: Starting with the 9.4 version, there is no flatzinc asset (or-tools_flatzinc_{XXX}_{VERSION}.zip) on github. Instead, one should use the `cpp` asset, e.g. `or-tools_amd64_archlinux_cpp_v9.5.2237.tar.gz` for  version 9.5 for arch linux. Additional source on the topic: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3457