# How can I install OR tools for Minizinc on Windows system?

Tags: windows, or-tools, minizinc

I have a Windows 10 laptop with Minizinc and Minizinc IDE. How Can i add the OR-Tools Solver?
Where can i get the Executable for my PC?
Once i have them i will add them as in the picture
Thanks Tamir

[image]

Comment: (Never tried this, but:) See Jips answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61535257/2320035) (and consider upvoting). Release binaries for or-tools can be found @ [Github Release Pages](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/tag/v9.1) (to future readers: Link is hard-coded v9.1): `or-tools_flatzinc_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v9.1.9490.zip` (under "assets"). (I checked the content of that file and it contains the binary Jip is referring to).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i install Google's CP solver OR-Tools in MiniZinc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61534787/how-can-i-install-googles-cp-solver-or-tools-in-minizinc)

Comment: I was able to do it and found out that i need C:/or-tools_flatzinc_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v9.1.9490/or-tools_flatzinc_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v9.1.9490/bin/fzn-or-tools.exe

Comment: Actually i fixed it alone 
and you need to select the fzn-ot-tools and not parser-or-tools

Comment: How can i change the vote of this the -2 is not fair. my question was valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I fixed it myself. You need to select the `fzn-ot-tools` and not `parser-or-tools`. I was able to do it and found out that I need:

```
C:/or-tools_flatzinc_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v9.1.9490/or-tools_flatzinc_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v9.1.9490/bin/fzn-or-tools.exe
```