# Error: syntax error, unexpected any; when using OR-Tools solver with Minizinc

Tags: or-tools, minizinc

I want to use the OR-Tools solver in combination with MiniZinc (IDE or CLI).
I followed the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61534787/how-can-i-install-googles-cp-solver-or-tools-in-minizinc/61535257#61535257). My MiniZincIDE is now set up like this: [image: screenshot of MiniZinc IDE solver configuration].

When I select the OR tools solver and try to run it on a simple .mzn model I get the following error:

```
(included from file '/home/my_username/lib/MiniZincIDE-2.5.5-bundle-linux-x86_64/share/minizinc/std/solver_redefinitions.mzn')
/home/my_username/lib/MiniZincIDE-2.5.5-bundle-linux-x86_64/bin/or-tools/share/minizinc/redefinitions-2.0.mzn:104.9-11:
        any: xx = [ x[i] | i in index_set(x) where occurs(v[i])];
        ^^^
Error: syntax error, unexpected any
(included from file '/home/my_username/lib/MiniZincIDE-2.5.5-bundle-linux-x86_64/share/minizinc/std/solver_redefinitions.mzn')
/home/my_username/lib/MiniZincIDE-2.5.5-bundle-linux-x86_64/bin/or-tools/share/minizinc/redefinitions-2.0.mzn:111.9-11:
        any: xx = [ x[i] | i in index_set(x) where occurs(v[i])];
        ^^^
Error: syntax error, unexpected any

Process finished with non-zero exit code 1
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a conflict between the version of OR-tools FlatZinc and the MiniZinc version you have installed (version 2.5.5). The `any` keyword in the FlatZinc definitions requires at least MiniZinc version 2.6.0.

If you update MiniZinc to the current version it should work.